# Android layout for the attached Image

Tags: android, android-layout

I tried creating layout for the attached image but it was looking very ugly, and then I erased it all and still thinking how to do it. Can someone please design a layout for the attached image, it will give me a idea on which layout is best suited for these designs and I'll customize it further.

[image: User profile layout]

If you look closely, there are three type of boxes:

1. which has a name, age , etc.
2. which has about me - it's a two-row box.
3. which has options for smoke, alcohol etc...

If you can design one box of each type, then I will have a fair idea of how to proceed ahead.

Comment: Is this data dynamic? I mean are they coming from server and will change? or are you hard coding it?

Comment: Number of items will remain same ... keys like name age. Body will remain same ... values will come from server

Comment: So the best approch would be using recyclerView. Just design different item layout and apply switch case is your adapter class. Should i give an example in answer?

Comment: Yes please give example, that would be helpful..

Comment: This is what we call a "free labour" question. It is important to Stack Overflow readers that the site does not become known as a place where tutorials written to your specific requirements, from scratch, can be requested. It is much better if you can show us the layout code you have so far, and what _specific_ problem you are having with it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't copy paste the code, read it and try to understand it.

You have to create different viewHolder class for different layout and attach different view in onCreateVIewHolder. Here is an example:

```
private Activity currActivity;
private Context currContext;
private List<CommonCategory> itemList;

public HomeFeedRecyclerAdapter(Activity currActivity, Context currContext, ArrayList<CommonCategory> itemList) {
this.itemList = itemList;
this.currActivity = currActivity;
this.currContext = currContext;
}


@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
View view;
RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder;

switch (viewType) {
case TYPE_ONE: {
    view = getLayoutView(parent, R.layout.list_one);
    viewHolder = new EditTextViewHolders(view, currActivity);
    break;
}
case TYPE_TWO: {
    view = getLayoutView(parent, R.layout.list_two);
    viewHolder = new TextViewHolders(view, currActivity, getItem(viewType));
    break;
}
default: {
    viewHolder = null;
}

}
return viewHolder;
}
```

Then create two different viewHolder class(in this case EditTextViewHolders and TextViewHolders) and define your views there. Just give specific ID to each layout to facilitate.